# How to reprovision hard disk after Windows 8 Storage Space

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-8.1, storage-spaces

I am rebuilding a PC. I have 4 hard disks and Windows 8.1 does not want to install on any of them. It is also see 3 of them as a single 'Storage Space' that I had created in a previous install of Windows 8.

I now just want to reset all the disks and start again.

I have tried DiskPart commands, but can't find anything that will do enough of a clean or reset to start again.

Anyone have any ideas bearing in mind that I have no OS on that machine at the moment and really don't particularly want to start pulling disks out and putting them into another machine if I can avoid it? So need to work from a booting USB stick!

Answer (score 0):

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/clean-install

In particular:

> 8.On the  Where do you want to install Windows? page, do one of the following:
>
> •In Windows 8.1, tap or click the partition that you want, tap or
>   click the formatting option you want to perform if needed, then follow
>   the instructions.
>
> •In Windows 8, tap or click Drive options (advanced), tap or click the
>   partition that you want to change, tap or click the formatting option
>   you want to perform if needed, then follow the instructions.

This will allow you to remove any existing partitions, create new ones, format them and install 8.1 where you like.

Comment: No it won't! That's why I am posting the question here. It can neither create partitions, format any of my disks!

Comment: try disconnecting 3 of the drives and just leave connected the one which you want to install to. adding the other three will be dead easy after and see if you still have the same issue

Comment: I also have a single disk in the system. I have cleaned it, partitioned it as GPT and MBR, formatted and not formatted, changed my bios to and from Legacy and UEFI and still cannot get Windows Installer to use any partitions. It says look in the logs but there are none!